# What to use in place of RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK for new Retrofit 2 API?

Tags: retrofit

In Retrofit 1.9.x there was a `RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK` that let you easily determine whether the failure was due to a network error or not. In the new 2.0 API we no longer have `RetrofitError` is there a simple equivalent we can use to test whether the `Response` failed due to the network?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source for the 1.9.0 version of Retrofit, it looks like the only time a `RetrofitError` of `Kind.NETWORK` is created is if there's an `IOException` when attempting to invoke a request. We should be able to just make the same check ourselves when using the new 2.0 API.

Comment: What do you mean same check?  Using android apis or retrofit apis?

Comment: I mean if you have an existing project using Retrofit 1.9.x, and you want to upgrade to Retrofit 2.0 with the minimum amount of effort, you'll need to change any code that's looking for a `RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK` to look for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK anymore.

onFailure will be called when a Network error occur, or an IOException will throw

Comment: Not everyone one uses the callbacks. What if you are using an `Observable`?

Comment: can't you use onError of subscriber? see https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters%2Frxjava%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fretrofit2%2Fadapter%2Frxjava%2FRxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java#L204

Comment: That is what I ended up using. Thanks.

Comment: this is a duplicate answer compared to @Jonathan Caryl 's answer